# New moon shaped css not working in safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I got this simple css shape that should resemble a new moon, in chrome and firefox everything looks fine, but in safari the outline of the whole circle is visible - how can I make this new moon shape work in safari as well?

[image: Safari result]

Img -> Current Safari result

```css
.circle {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-left: 10px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Comment: have you tried hiding the overflow or changing the border right colour to white?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in how webkit handles partial borders with `border-radius` set.

Here’s a method using `box-shadow` instead of borders, which I believe is visually similar:

```css
.circle-box-shadow {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  box-shadow: -10px 0 0 red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.circle-border {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-left: 10px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<p>Using <code>box-shadow</code>:</p>
<div class="circle-box-shadow"></div>
<br>
<p>Using <code>border</code>:</p>
<div class="circle-border"></div>
```

Tested in Chrome 70.0.3538.110 and Safari 12.0.1.